# Can't run xamarin app on real phone and GPS getLocation work slowly

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mobile

I create mobile app which use GPS location and it's task is to bring you to point on which you were inputted her coordinates. When you open the app you input the name, coordinate X and coordinate Y of the target point. After that click SAVE button and point will appair in the list of points. When you click on her, will show up new window.
When this view is active in output permanently, are shows issues like:
W/monodroid-assembly(19370): typemap: unable to find mapping to a Java type from managed type 'System.Int32, mscorlib'.

If you start debug of app, you will see the issues and that when hit the Compass_ReadingChanged method

"var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best);

var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);" are repeats many times."

Although that if I use emulator the app is running slowly, but if i deploy it on my phone it start and when input and tap ot the point it does not work.
If i comment the two lines with request and location and set default values the app run very fast and without problems.

Please if you see mistake somewhere help me.

This is link with the code https://github.com/NenkoPakov/StakeOut

If you click on image link below you will see the issues which I receive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx9jm.png)

Comment: use GeolocationAccuracy.Medium instead of GeolocationAccuracy.Best. "Beast" option is take some time to get location. because it try to get most accurate coordinates.
but still you need to use "Best" option then show a loading indicator.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i really need good accuracy. I will try it!

Comment: I ran your project on my side in emulator, it works fast and I did not see any error messages. Can you have a try with another simulator?